# Asp.Net Core Razor Pages localization date format is not read by Javascript locale

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, localization, razor-pages

I have borrowed a library from a theme that has a datepicker that makes use of the local datetime format, so while in development, it uses the format from my PC. I would like to work regardless of that, based on a configuration I have set in my App.
I have tried the code below in the Startup.cs Configure method, but it doesn't change anything.

```
var culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
var dateformat = new DateTimeFormatInfo
{
    ShortDatePattern = "dd/MM/yyyy",
    LongDatePattern = "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"
};
culture.DateTimeFormat = dateformat;

var supportedCultures = new[] { culture };

app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
{
    DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(culture),
    SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
    SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
});
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can't you just use a ISO8601 format, as provided by Javascript's `.toISOString()` method?

Comment: I tested your code, and it can work if I just use Datetime.Now. So could you please share the code about how to show the datetime? the library may override this setting.

Comment: The server side code works fine. The problem is commands from moment.js like moment.localeData(). Even if I have set the date format of the app as "dd/MM/yyyy", such commands return dates in a "MM/DD/YYYY", which is my PC's format.